# FFmpeg not copying chapters

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm experimenting with using ffmpeg to process some mkv files. The goal is ultimately to convert a bunch of H264 files to H265 to save space. However the part of the solution I'm experimenting with at the moment is to strip non-English streams from the output and currently my command looks like this

```
ffmpeg -i test.mkv -t 2 -map 0:v -map 0:m:language:eng -map_chapters 0 -c copy test-2.mkv
```

Ignore the `-t 2`, that's just while testing.

The problem I'm having is that the chapters are not being copied. In the `test.mkv` they look something like this

```
Menu
00:00:00.000                             : en:Chapter 01
00:02:24.519                             : en:Chapter 02
00:09:08.089                             : en:Chapter 03
00:11:00.618                             : en:Chapter 04
00:16:27.069                             : en:Chapter 05
...
```

But in the output `test-2.mkv` all I get is

```
Menu
00:00:00.000                             : :Chapter 01
```

So my question is what do I have wrong? I've tried all sorts of things including `-map_metadata` but can't see to get the chapters across.

PS. Here's what `ffprobe` thinks of the input file

```
ffprobe test.mkv
ffprobe version 5.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
[matroska,webm @ 0x141704960] Could not find codec parameters for stream 4 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
[matroska,webm @ 0x141704960] Could not find codec parameters for stream 5 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'test.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.0 + libmatroska v1.4.1
    creation_time   : 2020-11-01T07:51:03.000000Z
  Duration: 02:12:33.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 29792 kb/s
  Chapters:
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 144.519000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 01
    Chapter #0:1: start 144.519000, end 548.089000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 02
    Chapter #0:2: start 548.089000, end 660.618000
...
```

Comment: Try without `-t 2`. I never tried it, but you may try dumping metadata, and use the metadata file as described [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Metadata-1).

Comment: Ahh. I'm an idiot. It was the `-t 2` argument. It just never occurred to me that it would process the chapters and drop any beyond the end of the video and with the `-t 2` truncating the video to 2 seconds for testing purposes it was quite naturally dropping all chapters that where beyond that. Thanks.